FireDAC/Access database - cannot create FOREIGN KEY with ON DELETE CASCADE
Delphi win32 app, Access database: migrating from ADO to FireDAC
I’m in the process of migrating my Delphi 12 VCL windows application from MS Access database to PostgreSQL  .
My first step is to migrate the provider from ADO to FireDAC.
Using ADO I could create a new table with referentiual integrity towards an existing table using a TADOQuery:
CREATE TABLE Absence ( 
  ID COUNTER, 
  ManID INTEGER, 
  ...(felter udeladt)...
  CONSTRAINT Absence_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID), 
  CONSTRAINT Absence_Men_FK FOREIGN KEY (ManID) REFERENCES Men ON DELETE CASCADE
);


But with a FireDAC TFDQuery I get the error
EMSAccessNativeExceptionexception message  : [FireDAC][Phys][ODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in CONSTRAINT clause.
If I remove "ON DELETE CASCADE" the error is gone.
Can't FireDAC create cascading delete? I get the feeling reading
text
Is it a limitation of ODBC?

I'd hook up a FD monitor component and see exactly what FD is sending to the engine. Sometimes FD makes edits to your SQL and if you know exactly what it is doing you can maybe try something different.
